# ZEND: Cannot Access Post Data

Tags: php, zend-framework

Greets.
{{Solved}}
In order to get POST data you MUST use $this->formHidden in order to hold all the data. Even though variables are inside the  they don't get passed if they aren't in some sort of form item.

I am unable to access post data in ZEND.

Path of User -
START
INDEX PAGE
 ->Submit Page
   ->Pay Page

I created a controller, extended the Zend Controller, and added an action called payAction. The user can go from the Index Page to the Submit Page. After I have all their data inside variables, I used a form and a submit button to go to the "pay page". However, I cannot get any of the POST data.

```
public function payAction()
{
 $data = $this->getRequest();
}
```

I have tried putting getRequest, getParam, getRawBody inside that controller function.
In the page itself I have tried.

```
echo 'Hello';
   echo $request;
   echo $data;
   echo $_POST['payZip'];
   echo $_POST['data'];
   echo $_POST[$data];
   echo $request;
   echo $this->values['payZip'];
   echo $payZip;
   echo $this->values['shippingDone'];
   echo $stuff;
```

Is there ANYTHING I can place in my controller or in my view in order to get my post data? I used a form method="post" and a button and it DOES allow me to get to the page. I can see Hello. But NONE of the post data is available.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you.

-- Update

```
    $data = $this->getRequest();
    $param = $this->_request->getParam('payZip');

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
    print_r($this->_getAllParams());
    echo $param;
    }
```

Doing that gives me -
HelloArray ( [controller] => wheel [action] => pay [module] => default [shipping] => UPS Ground [payPal] => Secure Payment System )

But I still can't print payZip... I did echo and nothing comes out.

Comment: I updated my answer to, as I noticed how you where echoing stuff out.  See my "EDIT" section below.  I will add a little more detail to my answer for better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get parameters from Zend Framework you need to do this in the Action Controller:

```
$data = $this->_request->getParams();
```

You can also get individual params like this

```
$param = $this->_request->getParam('payZip');
```

What it appears your doing wrong is you're only getting the "request object".  You need to then call that objects method to get the request data.

Here's some simple code I often use when testing parameters:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    #::DEBUG:: 
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->_request->getParams()); echo '</pre>';
    #::DEBUG:: 
}
```

This will show all your parameters.  What you will notice is that you will also get the names of the Module, Controller and Action with your params.

**EDIT**

Ps.  If you're trying to use the parameter in the view script you need to do this:

```
echo $this->data['payZip'];

echo $this->param;
```

In your Action Controller, you save your data to the "view" object by doing this:

```
$this->view->myVariable = 'Hello';
```

But when you're in a view script, you are *IN* the view script, so `$this` represents `$this->view` from the action controller.

So, you access the variable like this:

```
echo $this->myVariable;
```

Wrapping everything into a bigger code chunk for understanding:

Your Controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    // get all parameters and pass them to the view
    $this->view->params = $this->_request->getParams();
    // get an individual parameter and pass it to the view
    $this->view->payZip = $this->_request->getParam('payZip');
}
```

Your View Script

```
<!-- Dump all parameters -->
<pre><?php print_r($this->params); ?></pre>
<!-- Print payZip -->
<p>My PayZip is: <?php echo $this->payZip; ?></p>
<!-- Print payZip from full parameter array -->
<p>My PayZip (array) is: <?php echo $this->data['payZip']; ?></p>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I used your debug function and it prints   [controller] => wheel
    [action] => pay
    [module] => default
    [shipping] => UPS Ground
    [payPal] => Secure Payment System

Comment: I got it figured out. Thank you so much. Each variable HAS to be in the form of a $this->formHidden for it to show up. I will update my question to reflect this.